# Do I need to call SSL_library_init if I am just using EVP-based hash implementations?

Tags: openssl

The documentation for `SSL_library_init()` on my system states:

```
NOTES
   SSL_library_init() must be called before any other action takes place. 
   SSL_library_init() is not reentrant.
```

I am interested in using the EVP suite of hash functions. E.g. `EVP_DigestInit_ex`, `EVP_DigestUpdate` and `EVP_DigestFinal_ex`.

`EVP_DigestInit_ex` and the rest are in `libcrypto`, while `SSL_library_init()` is in `libssl`. I would like to minimize the number of linked libraries. Do I need to call `SSL_library_init()` if I am not using SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need to call

```
 OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms ();
```

It will load all the encryption and digest algorithms.

I assume you are more interested in ciphers.

If you are interested in using SSL related feature, you need to call `SSL_library_init`.

Since, you are interested in hash algorithms, use

```
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am just interested in the digest algorithms, not in the ciphers.